# How to determine if variables have significant impact on binary outcome?

Tags: regression, correlation

I have the following dataset with discrete, boolean, and categorical variables :

```
'data.frame':   133778 observations of  23 variables:
 $ id                : num  10 100 1000 1000157 1000183 ...
 $ age               : int  30 3 48 52 32 32 52 28 40 36 ...
 $ bikeAvailability  : chr  "FOR_SOME" "NO" "FOR_SOME" "FOR_ALL" ...
 $ employed          : chr  "true" "false" "true" "true" ...
 $ hasLicense        : chr  "no" "no" "yes" "yes" ...
 $ ptHasGA           : chr  "true" "true" "false" "false" ...
 $ sex               : chr  "f" "f" "m" "f" ...
```

I also have a subset of this data set (~30'000 observations) with people who chose to travel by car instead of another mode of transport. I want to analyze if any of the variables have a significant impact on the behavioral choice to take the car.

I have read [this](https://thestatsgeek.com/2015/01/17/why-shouldnt-i-use-linear-regression-if-my-outcome-is-binary/), which sais linear regression is the wrong approach for binary outcomes (which is in my case taking the car or not).

What would be the appropriate approach or test for this type of analysis? Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

That is correct, when your target variable is binary you should use logistic regression (or logit), a linear model for classification instead of linear regression. There are many other models of course but that is a start.

You can check an example here: https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/logit-regression/.